# Add a ScrollArea inside a GridLayout

Tags: qt, scroll, grid-layout, qscrollarea

I've got a GridLayout, and when I click a button it adds a row. So if there is lots of rows, the window is too high. I would like to put a scrollArea inside it, when there is for example 5 rows.

It is possible to do it, and if yes, is it possible to add the scroll area below the first line of the grid layout (I've got the titles of my columns here)

Comment: You can't do that with `QGridLayout`. I did make bad experience with abusing a `QGridLayout` for table widgets. You *can* make something similar to scrolling by hiding the first row widgets and showing the one-past-the-last row widgets (which would simulate item-wise scrolling). But really that's a pain in the ass (and when you start painting into the table for filling cells or stuff, you will notice that `QGridLayout::cellRect` is broken if the table contains height-for-width items - at least for me it just didn't work). Best use `QTableView`.

Comment: QTableView seems to be difficul to implement. How I simply add a widget in a specific cell?

Comment: You can just add scroll area to the window and put grid layout into it. It will be effectively the same as you suggest. You can add another layout up to scroll area and display titles in that layout. The only problem is column widths. You need to set fixed widths or maintain the same widths as in main layout manually. You can also use `QTableWidget`, it seems to be appropriate and is easier to use than `QTableView`. (You can easily add widgets to `QTableWidget`'s cells.)

Comment: QTableWidget was that I was looking for